# Coordinate Matrix

Tags: vector-spaces

I am really struggling with the concept of coordinate vectors and hence coordinate matrix in vector spaces. It would be great if anyone could provide me any intuitive picture to understand it.

Comment: The coordinate vector is a vector which contains the coefficients needed to combinate linearly your basis vectors in order to span a given vector $v$. Say, for example, that you are working in $\Bbb{R}^2$ with the base $(e_1,e_2)=(\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix})$ and you want to express the vector $v=\begin{pmatrix}2\\5\end{pmatrix}$ than your coordinate vector is $b=\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2\\5\end{pmatrix}$ because $v = a_1e_1 + a_2e_2$.
What do you mean with coordinate matrix? Could you post some background?

Comment: By coordinate matrix, I mean the matrix of vector with respect to the given basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a basis $\left \{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 5 \\ \end{bmatrix} \right \}$.  You want to express the vector $\left \{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} \right \}$ in terms of your two basis vectors.

That is, you want to find numbers $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ such that $c_{1}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ \end{bmatrix}+ c_{2}\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 5 \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$.

But if we actually multiply the numbers into the vectors, we get:

$\begin{bmatrix} c_{1} \\ 2c_{1} \\ \end{bmatrix}+ \begin{bmatrix} 3c_{2} \\ 5c_{2} \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$.

Adding the vectors gives:

$\begin{bmatrix} c_{1} + 3c_{2} \\ 2c_{1} + 5c_{2} \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$.

But the above matrix equation is what you get if you multiply out $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ 2 & 5 \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} c_{1} \\ c_{2} \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$, and you would solve this matrix by writing it as an augmented matrix:

$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}1 &3&1 \\ 2 & 5 & 1\end{array}\right]$, and row reducing it.  You would get

$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c} 1 & 0  & -2 \\ 0 & 1  & 1 \\ \end{array}\right]$.  This would be give $c_{1} = -2$ and $c_{2} = 1$.  So that means:

$-2\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ \end{bmatrix}+ 1\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 5 \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$

Thus, in the "basis" of the two vectors $\left \{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 5 \\ \end{bmatrix} \right \}$, $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$ is actually the vector $\begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$.

The vector $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$ is with respect to the standard basis $\left \{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} \right \}$, but when we change the basis for $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, we get a different representation of the vector.  If I were you, I would go talk to a linear algebra teacher about what a change of basis actually looks like.  They will be able to draw the $XY$-plane on a board under the standard basis and under a new basis to show you what we mean.

Comment: Here is a nice picture of what I mean.  On the left, you see the vector with respect to the standard basis (it just looks like the $XY$-plane).  On the right, you see the $x$- and $y$-axes tilted.  The titled axes represent the basis vectors, which are now different from the standard basis of $\left \{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} \right \}$.  The new basis vectors are the new axes.  http://brickisland.net/cs177fa12/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/ddg_change_of_basis.svg